# Get What's app contacts profile picture android

Tags: android, image, whatsapp

Hi I am trying to get what's app contacts profile pictures. Is it possible? where they store all the profile pictures of users? 
Thanks!

Comment: Any changes on this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What's App does not provide any API for accessing their profile pictures.

Answer (score 2):

It's true there is no WhatsApp API for this, but it is certainly possible.

You can lookup contact images via the Android [`ContactsContract`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html) classes.

There are two types of Contact in the android database - `RawContact` and a `Contact`. The latter being an aggregation (representing a person) of a set of the former (representing individual accounts).

I suggest you first make sure the photo is cached on the device (just to avoid false flags while testing - open the contacts full image in WhatsApp and you can be sure it's cached) then you to get it programmatically (from API 14):

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

Cursor contactCursor = cr.query(
        ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
        new String[] { ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID, ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID } ,
        ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + "= ?",
        new String[] { "com.whatsapp" }, null);
if (contactCursor  != null && contactCursor .moveToFirst()) {
    String whatsappContactId = contactCursor.getString(contactCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID));
    Uri photoId = ContentUris.withAppendedId(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, whatsappContactId);
    Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(photoId, RawContacts.DisplayPhoto.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
}
```